# How to switch to full .NET stack in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, project.json

I created a new ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (vNext) project in VS 2015.

I imported some classes from another project, but looks like the DNX is missing some classes that are very essential to me.

Can I choose to use the full .NET stack instead of the DNX?
What do I have to change? I like the new *config.json* file better than the old method, but what do I have to change the reference to.

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the core line, as in:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { }
},
```

From the [asp 5 docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html#building-applications-with-net-core) (Highlighted relevant parts):

> **dnx451 represents the .NET Framework**, while dnxcore50 represents .NET
> Core 5 (5.0).
>
> ...
>
> The recommendation from the ASP.NET team is to
> target both frameworks with new applications. If you want to only
> target .NET Core, remove dnx451, **or only target .NET Framework, remove
> dnxcore50, from the frameworks listed in project.json**. Note that
> ASP.NET 4.6 and earlier target and require the .NET Framework, as they
> always have.